# Get project and file associated with IXtextDocument

Tags: xtext

From a context menu an instance of `IXtextDocument` can be obtained using the active editor

```
IXtextDocument xtextDocument = EditorUtils.getActiveXtextEditor().getDocument();
```

How can the file name of the document and the project name in which the document is stored be obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IResource` adapter like this:

```
IXtextDocument xtextDocument = ...
IResource resource = xtextDocument.getAdapter(IResource.class);
IProject project = resource.getProject();
```

Comment: for filename info `resource.getLocationURI()`